# Safari won't wait for user for Google sign-in redirect to iOS application

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, google-signin, gidsignin

In my application I am using Google SignIn as Login to my application. I am not using cocoa pods I am directly using frameworks by pasting in my project. I am configuring GIDSignIn class like below.

```
//Allowing to sign in through browser
self.googleSignIn.allowsSignInWithBrowser = YES;
self.googleSignIn.allowsSignInWithWebView = NO;

//Initiate sign in
[self.googleSignIn signIn];
```

When i clicks on Google SignIn button it will redirect me to Safari (Not SFSafariViewController) and asks for google account credentials, everything is working fine. Once i allow to get the application to use my basic profile data, a pop up will appear in Safari for redirecting to my application and if I selects open it will go back to my application (Proper redirect URL is given) with the basic profile information. But problem is when I don't select an option of the alert view in safari for redirecting. It will close the alert view by itself and i will be in safari and no information will be redirected to my application. How to make the alertview wait for user response?

[image] 
It will ask for user permission and once allow is pressed i will get the following screen.

[image]

And now if i don't select anything, the alert view dismisses and stays in Safari. Only if i press "Open" it will take me to MyApplication and gets me user basic profile application. Please help me how to stop alertview getting dismissed by itself.

Comment: I have the same issue, please help.